# How to make the following readAsDataURL return multiple readAsDataURLs?

Tags: javascript, file

This function read files gotten from an input field and return their dataUrls:

```
readAsDataURL (target) {
  // target => <input type="file" id="file">
  var reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      resolve(event.target.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(target.files[0])
  })
},
```

As you can see, the function only deals with single files. I want to return multiple files. I tried doing `reader.readAsDataURL(target.files)` but got this error: `'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

How to make the function return multiple dataUrls?

Comment: Just a note, if you are trying to display multiple media files into the doc, through e.g `<img>` or `<video>`, then don't even go the `FileReader` way : `URL.createObjectURL()` is synchronous, takes no time, no memory, and should always be preferred to heavy dataURIs

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, I didn't know about this. Could you write an answer with a sample code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)? You might be able to do something like:

```
fileToDataURL(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      resolve(event.target.result)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}  

readAsDataURL (target) {
  // target => <input type="file" id="file">
  var filesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.files)      
  return Promise.all(filesArray.map(fileToDataURL))
}
```

This essentially does the same thing you had setup, but creates a promise for each one, returning the result in an array only once all have been completed.

---

I forgot that you cannot treat `target.files` directly as an array, so it needs to be converted first. For this you can use: `Array.prototype.slice.call(target.files)`

Comment: Correct approach using `Promise.all`, but there is no `map` method on `FileList` objects

Comment: Kaiido is right: `TypeError: target.files.map is not a function` What's the correct way then?

Comment: Have updated my answer to include converting the files to a proper array

Comment: @MattWay Thanks. It also works like this: `return Promise.all([...target.files].map(utils.fileToDataURL))` (For some miraculous reason.)

Comment: You are right. The spread operator essentially does the same thing as the slice call I used. I would use your method (just forgot about it).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the question what you'll do with these dataURIs, but most of the time, you don't actually need it.

To be able to display a media from a user's File, or from a Blob, into your document, it is better to use the [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method which will return a blobURI, that you can use like any url.

Non exhaustive list of blobURIs advantages :

- **is synchronous**. You don't need your Promise wrapping event handlers hell, all can be done in a single loop.
- **is fast**. The browser doesn't read the File or Blob passed, it just creates a symlink in the memory to the real File in the HDD.
- **is memory light-weight**. Because of previous point. When compared to `readAsDataURL()`, you should note that this latter will first read the file entirely, convert it to a base64 string (~34% bigger than original data), and finally, you will store this big string in the DOM's markup, making it always present in memory. From then, the browser will read it again, convert it to binary, read it again as binary and finally process it as an normal resource.

  ---

#### *"But I need to send it to the server !"*

Then send the File directly, as multipart data. Less work on the front-side, less work in the pipes (remember ~34%), and less work server-side if you wanted to save a File there.
Most server-side languages have easy built-ins methods to catch Files from POST requests, and you can send it easily from the front with the [`FormData` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object).

---

Here is an example of your code, using blobURIs, which excpects all Files are images.

```js
document.querySelector('input').onchange = function(){
  // FileList doesn't have an forEach method yet
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.files, function(file){
    if(file.type.indexOf('image/' === 0)){
      var i = new Image();
      i.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);  // creates a blobURI
      document.body.appendChild(i);
      }
    });
  };
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

---

But note that this method can also have **cons** :

- Don't use it with MediaStreams. It will lock the source of the MediaStream until the blobURI is revoked (either when `URL.revokeObject(blobURI)` is called, or on an hard refresh of the page. In this case, you should use `mediaElement.srcObject = MediaStream;` instead.
- For Blobs you created, (not coming from an `<input>`), the same point applies : the blob will be stuck in memory until expressly released. In this case, simply call `URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURI)` once the resource is loaded.

  ```
  img.onload = URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); 
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(the_Blob_I_built);
  ```

Comment: i LOVE you :* !!