# code is working while debug, but without not - Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I have an issue that I don't understand and I have no idea how to fix it, where to look for the cause. When I'm debugin (chrome) every thing is working, but during normal use it dosen't. For me is some kind of Science-Fiction, it would be better for me if it's more Science than Fiction :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < filteredAddedFiles.length; i++) {
  if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(filteredAddedFiles[i].name)) {

    (function (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var blob = b64toBlob(file.base64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''), file.type);
      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {

        console.log(this);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        image.onload = function () {
          preview.innerHTML += drawHtml(image, file)
        };

        //I tried:
        //(function (b) {
        //  var image = new Image();
        //  image.addEventListener("load", function () {
        //    preview.innerHTML += drawHtml(this, file);
        //    //window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
        //  });
        //  image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
        //})(blob);
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
    })(filteredAddedFiles[i]);

  } else {
    errors += filteredAddedFiles[i].name + " Unsupported Image extension\n";
  }
}
```

here I attached a short movie that shows how its working
[link to movie](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1odYsBgGonlpWWQm1RMZxgUCuzTKA116h)

**not working** - I mean - it looks like the all thing inside `for` dosen't executed

**EDIT: 1**

@Teemu - I turn on logs in chrome console and all `console.log`'s appear

@Katie.Sun - now the above `for` - `console.log(filteredAddedFiles.length);` is `0` - but when I'm debuging code the same `console.log(filteredAddedFiles.length);` have values !

**EDIT: 2**

@Matti Price
`filteredAddedFiles` - is the result of custom logic of page, filtering, 
validation etc.
*Everything starts here:*

```
addedFiles = added(files); // files - FileList from input this is a read only array of obj

function added(from) {
            var out = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
                (function (obj) {
                    var readerBase64 = new FileReader();
                    readerBase64.addEventListener("load", function () {
                        var fileBase64 = readerBase64.result;
                        var row = { name: obj.name, size: obj.size, type: obj.type, base64: fileBase64 }
                        out.push(row);
                    });
                    readerBase64.readAsDataURL(obj); 
                })(from[i]);
            }
            return out;
        }
```

then `addedFiles` - do something farther and transform into `filteredAddedFiles` later. what I found in `added` function? during debug there is an `length` value witch is correct, but when I opened the `__proto__: Array(0)` I found `length` property = 0.

Should this `length` value be equal to the value from above `length`?

[image: print screen]

The second thing:
I have to admit that I don't have enough knowledge aboute `addEventListener`. Are there any queues here or some thread etc?

<s>**EDIT: 3**
After last @Teemu comment I made some changes (I had to read a lot aboute promisses etc:)), but output is the same `console.log("out resolve", out);` shows a array of object, but `console.log("out.length then", out.length);` shows `0` and the `small blue i-icon` show msg - `Value below evaluated just now`</s>

```
var out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fillArray(files[i], out);
}
console.log("out resolve", out);
console.log("out.length then", out.length);

function fillArray(obj, out) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var readerBase64 = new FileReader();
        readerBase64.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var fileBase64 = readerBase64.result;
            var row = { name: obj.name, size: obj.size, type: obj.type, out.push(row);
            resolve(out);
        });
        readerBase64.readAsDataURL(obj); 
    });
}
```

After I posted the edit above I relized that I just create `promise`, I forgot to call `promise

*, but this is not important, because 90% of my code has been changed because of this topic and the answer of the Golden Person* **@Kaiido**

[URL.createObjectURL() - is synchronous. You don't need your Promise wrapping event handlers hell, all can be done in a single loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511563/how-to-make-the-following-readasdataurl-return-multiple-readasdataurls)

In my case, this is a better solution than a filereader, I have to upload only images, and with some restrictions thanks to which I don't have to worry about freeze the Internet browser, because of the `synchronous` nature of `createObjectURL()`
Thank you for your help and commitment

Comment: You should write down what is not working. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: not working - it looks like the all thing inside `for` dosen't executed

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Then the first thing to do is to check the value of `filteredAddedFiles.length` before the loop.

Comment: `console.log(this)` do nothing in console, right know for testing I added `console.log(blob)` below the`'console.log(this)` and it's the same - nothing heppend + function `drawHtml` dosent render anything

Comment: I added `console.log(filteredAddedFiles.length)` below 'for' and nothing shows up in console

Comment: @Teemu @szkut also `if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(filteredAddedFiles[i].name))` could be evaluating to false

Comment: @szkut you have to check the length before you hit the for loop. on the line before

Comment: @Teemu @Katie.Sun - I commented out the `if` statment with `test` and add `console.log(filteredAddedFiles.length);` before `for` - and still it dosen't work (it working only while debug, but the console log don't show in console as well)

Comment: @szkut how are you calling this part of your code? if you just do a `console.log("here");` before the for loop and run it normally, what happens? Because if the answer is nothing then whatever is causing this problem is not in the block of code you posted

Comment: @Teemu I'm testing with chrome.
@Katie.Sun - it's like you said - `console.log("here");` - and nothing -, I will write when I found something

Comment: Make sure the logs are shown, "Default" should be selected from "Log levels".

Comment: I turn on logs in chrome console and all `console.log`'s appear - but there isn't any error

Comment: Where is `filteredAddedFiles` coming from?

Comment: @Matti Price, sedond edit post

Comment: The problem is, that the first filereader load listener is not executed when you return `out`. Hence the array is empty at the time you're trying to iterate it. Chrome console also works asynchronously, hover over the small blue i-icon to see more information. If the code works when the DevTools are actually opened, that maybe happens because logging takes a few microseconds which might be enough to populate `out`. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).